# how to put return value into URL in java script

Tags: javascript, vue.js, url, url-rewriting, vue-component

I have the value for "breedKey" from parent page and "thedate" from  return already, how can I put these two value into axios.get URL, I would like to replace them in URL this way

"https://www.mustavi.com/TimeSeries/?param1={{breedkey}}&param2={{thedate}}"

```
   props: ["breedKey", "time"],

    data() {
            return {
              thedate: this.time
            };
          },

    async created() {


            try {
              this.promise = axios.get(
                "https://www.mustavi.com/TimeSeries/?param1=nctzenselcaday&param2=2020-04-09"
              );
              const res = await this.promise;
```

Comment: You want to do this, right? Url+"/?param1="+myparam1+"&param2="+myparam2?  Or I am not getting you properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for this

```
this.promise = axios.get(
 `https://www.mustavi.com/TimeSeries/?param1=${this.breedKey}&param2=${this.thedata}`
);
```

Comment: I just found out that it error if I declare
let myparam1 = breedKey;
let myparam2 = thedate;
before the try {}